# Formik reset button doesn't clear the form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have the following:

```
    <Formik initialValues={{}} onSubmit={data => console.log(data)}>
        <Form className="h-full">
            <FieldsWrapper className="hide-scrolling-bar">
                {filters?.map(filter => (
                    <FiltersGroup
                        name={filter.label}
                        filters={filter.children}
                    />
                ))}
            </FieldsWrapper>

            <ButtonsWrapper>
                <Button type="submit" text="apply all" isPrimary />
                <Button
                    type="reset"
                    text="clear all"
                    isWishList
                    isPrimary={false}
                />
            </ButtonsWrapper>
        </Form>
    </Formik>
```

however the reset button doesn't clear the form

FILTERGROUP COMPONENT

```
...
const FiltersGroup = ({filters, name}) => {
    const Checkbox = ({
        field: {name, value, onChange, onBlur},
        id,
        label,
        className,
        ...props
    }) => {
        return (
            <div className="flex">
                <input
                    name={name}
                    id={id}
                    type="checkbox"
                    value={label}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    className="hidden"
                    {...props}
                />
                <SizeLabel htmlFor={id}>{label}</SizeLabel>
            </div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <div className="mb-10">
            <GroupLabel>{name}</GroupLabel>
            <div className="flex flex-wrap">
                {filters?.map(filter => (
                    <Field
                        component={Checkbox}
                        name={name}
                        id={`id-${filter}`}
                        label={filter}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default FiltersGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the fields into a Formik tag then:

```
<Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    validateOnBlur={false}
    validateOnChange={false}
    onSubmit={async (values, { resetForm }) => {
      await onSubmit(values)

      resetForm()
    }}
  >
    ....
```

When you click Submit button it reset automatically

**EDIT:**
Example:

```
const initialValues = {
    name: ''
}
               <Formik
                    initialValues={initialValues}>
                    {formik => {
                        console.log('formik props', formik)
                        return (
                            <div>
                                <h1>EDIT USER</h1>
                                <Form>
                                <Field name="name" type="text" />
                <br/><br/><br/>
                                    <div>
                                        <button type="reset" onClick={()=>formik.resetForm()}>
                                            Reset All
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </Form>
                            </div >
                        )
                    }}
                </Formik >
```

In your case:

```
<Formik initialValues={{}} onSubmit={data => console.log(data)}>
{formik => {
    <Form className="h-full">
        <FieldsWrapper className="hide-scrolling-bar">
            {filters?.map(filter => (
                <FiltersGroup
                    name={filter.label}
                    filters={filter.children}
                />
            ))}
        </FieldsWrapper>

        <ButtonsWrapper>
            <Button type="submit" text="apply all" isPrimary />
            <Button
                type="reset"
                text="clear all"
                isWishList
                isPrimary={false}
                onClick={()=>formik.resetForm()}
            />
        </ButtonsWrapper>
    </Form>


}}

</Formik>
```

Comment: that makes sense, but I also need to do it by clicking on the reset button without submitting the form

Comment: I've edited the comment with the correct answer, i've tested it and works perfect, check it and let me know. InitialValues is the initial values of the fields you have to declare it first. It renders through the formik props and it access to  all the methods. I have write a console.log so you can check it

Comment: Can you check my answer, and vote for it useful or not useful. Thanks